# Qt embedded PID of focused window

Tags: qt, framebuffer, qtembedded

I use Qt Embedded, which directly draws to framebuffer. Is there a way to get pid of focused window? I tried to use QWSServer, but I didn't find all API for this. Thank You!

Comment: you mean only qt app or any ?

Comment: yes, only qt applications. All my gui is built on qt

Answer (score 1):

It's not so easy, checked it and PID can be found only by `QCoreApplication::instance()->applicationPid()`. Any reason to use PID ? maybe simple use `QWSWindow::client()->clientId()` to see it is a different app ?